# How to tell if my old Mac supports Sidecar feature in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, sidecar

This is a useful feature added to macOS Catalina. But how to tell if older hardware will support this new feature?

Answer (score 3):

I found a quick way to distinguish it. macOS Catalina seems to use Intel's HEVC hardware encoding. So as long as your old Mac has the 6th generation (Skylake 6xxx Series) or newer Intel processor, it definitely supports this feature.

[HEVC hardware encode on macOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/503/) 29:30

[image]

---

Blacklist found by [Steve Troughton-Smith](https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/1136413491462594560)

> Sidecar supports iMac 27" (Late 2015) or newer, MacBook Pro (2016) or newer, mac Mini (2018), Mac Pro (2019), MacBook Air (2018) , MacBook (Early 2016 or newer), and blacklists all the devices in the screenshot.
>
> [image]
>   ‏

Comment: If you want to verify this answer, you can just test the  Late 2015 21.5"(iMac16,2) and  27"(iMac17,1), these two models are released at the same time but have different gen of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Apple stated that Sidecar is part of Catalina so if the [hardware supports Catalina then it will support Sidecar](https://www.apple.com/macos/catalina-preview/).

[image]

Comment: I believe that I read that certain macs will run Catalina but will not run sidecar (I believe the article was on cult of Mac, and only 2016+ models support sidecar) https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.iclarified.com/71159/these-are-the-macs-that-officially-support-sidecar/amp

Comment: It's possible but the person that's saying that is someone who hacked the code and is providing his opinion.  Apple hasn't released anything else on Sidecar supported models, other that what's on their site right now.